# Limitations of a No-Install C# Application?

Tags: c#, winforms, privileges

I'm using SharpDevelop to create a WinForm-based C# application. After studying my target audience, I believe it is in my best interest to use a no-install application. While creating my `HelloWorld!` program to get to know SharpDevelop (I have just switched from VBExpress), I found that the file it outputs is a .exe without any setup process. However, I'm worried that some of the features I want won't be compatible with this format. I don't want to get deep into this app and find out users are going to have to keep the program in the same directory as 548 other random files.

Here are the features I'm concerned about:

+Save user data (XML) in AppData. 
+Access internet feeds (XML and/or JSON). 
+Minimize to tray on close.

Also, are there any common pitfalls with this type of deployment method?

EDIT: I understand the enduser will need the .NET framwork for C# programs. I am not worried about this.

Comment: Why do you think that any of these features have any dependency on deployment technique?

Comment: @John I'm worried that since the program is not installed, it will have less permissions, or that some sort of .dll must be included.

Comment: Well that's why I asked, isn't it?

Comment: @John: It's reasonable to assume that an app might need to be "registered" in order to run as with full trust.

Comment: I suppose I might have thought of that, if the OP had said anything about trust. But "less permissions, or that some sort of .dll must be included" made me want to ask, instead of assuming he was concerned about trust.

Comment: From the question, it is clear that you have little knowledge about installers, so you might spend some time learning them. Generally speaking, they are only automated tools that help you copy the binaries and configure settings. Thus, installers themselves do not give your applications any extra permissions. Visual Studio does have setup projects to help create installers, but SharpDevelop also bundles WiX which serves the same goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will execute with the same privileges.

The only thing you will want to look out for is making sure the end user has the correct .NET framework installed since you don't have an installer to do that for you.  But now reading the end of your message it appears you already have that covered.

If you are concerned about the deployment technique you can test it on a non-dev machine, though the results should be the exact same.

Comment: I appreciate your helpfulness, regardless of my ignorance.

Comment: Hey don't mind the people hating.  No question is a bad question.  Your question was well written, showed some initial research, laid out what your concerns were, and let us know what you were unsure about.  And welcome to SO!

Comment: Where was the hate? I wanted to know if he had some particular concern or not, so that I could address it.